# Two iFrames One scroll

Tags: iframe

I have 2 iframes one on top of each other.

- each iframe loads a different page.
- iframe 1 is the header
- iframe 2 is the content

desire

- behave as one page, so when you scroll the entire page scrolls

issue

- only the bottom one scrolls

Is there a way to do this?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>Untitled</title>
            <style type="text/css">
            body, html
            {
                margin: 0; padding: 0; 
            }

            #content
            {
                position:absolute; left: 0; right: 0; bottom: 0; top: 90px; background: blue; height: expression(document.body.clientHeight-90); overflow:hidden;
            }
        </style>
</head>
<body>

    <iframe src="http://www.example.com" width="100%" height="100" frameborder="0" scrolling="no"></iframe><br />

     <div id="content">
        <iframe src="http://www.cnn.com" width="100%" height="100%" frameborder="0"></iframe>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

If PHP is an option for you, you can use the include() function to import the page header and body content from other files.  This will construct the two pages into one and will scroll all as one.

The one drawback to this (from what you're doing already) is that whenever a hyperlink is followed from the page body, the header reloads on the next page.
(versus the header being static and not refreshing every time and new page is navigated to)

```
<?php
  // Page Header
  include("headerfile.html");
  // Page Body
  include("bodyfile.html");
?>
```

Likewise, you could just put the content for the body on that file.

```
<?php
  // Page Header
  include("headerfile.html");
?>
<!--content html goes here-->
```